# Paginacion manual datatable SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql-server

Hola que tal tengo una tabla de mas de 30 mil registros y uso serverside para mostrar los datos, pero no quiero que cargue todo de un solo golpe si no que cargue de forma distinta así como en caso MYSQL SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 15, 10, ahi funciona con un limit pero datatable es distinto muestra el total lo que busco es mostrar poco a poco así avanzando con la paginación echa por el datatable.

Ejemplo datatable: paginacion datatable 1,2,3,4
pagina del 1 al 10 muestra 10 registros ahi se ejecuta la consulta.
pagina del 11 al 20 muestra 10 registros ahi de nuevo se ejecuta la consulta.

Pero yo uso SQL SERVER.

Comment: Leí 3 veces la pregunta y no entiendo lo que quieres lograr. La redacción puede mejorar mucho, sugiero que le dediques unos minutos a asegurarte de expresar tu problema con orden y mayor claridad. Incluye ejemplos, algunos datos o analogías si consideras que hace falta, por no hablar de código.

Comment: Lo edite espero sea mas entendible

Comment: Si estas usando datatable, el plugin necesita tener la tabla con todos los registros y te muestra una paginacion segun el numero de resultados. Para no cargar lo 30 mil registros en una sola vista lo que te queda es hacer tu paginador propio y deshabilitar el paginador de datatable

Comment: @jachguate, me pregunto si esa sentencia pertenece a alguna versión de SqlServer en específico, la que yo conozco es `SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY id OFFSET @SKIP ROWS FETCH NEXT @NumResultados ROWS ONLY;` donde `@SKIP` son los resultados que se 'saltan' y `@NumResultados` es la cantidad de resultados que vas a devolver. Ambos parameters son `INT` y la cláusula `ORDER BY` es obligatoria

Comment: @Arriel, tienes toda la razón, mi sintaxis es incorrecta. Por lo mismo, borro el comentario, ya que no aporta nada, gracias por la corrección.